# Excel VBA Advanced Filter Problem

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu fiz um programa no VBA para calcular o custo na minha empresa. Para isso usei duas conexões com o banco de dados da Oracle.
O que é estranho é o fato de que quando tento utilizar o filtro avançado manualmente, ele funciona. Porém, quando tento usar o VBA (gravado através de macro usando o filtro manualmente), ele não funciona.

```
Sub custo()

'atualizacao da data
For Each c In Worksheets("BD2").Range("B1:B152")
 If c.Value <> "MOV_DATMOV" Then
 c.Value = ">" & DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date)
 Else
 c.Value = "MOV_DATMOV"
 End If
Next c

For Each d In Worksheets("BD2").Range("C1:C152")
 If d.Value <> "MOV_DATMOV" Then
 d.Value = "<" & Date
 Else
 d.Value = "MOV_DATMOV"
 End If
Next d

'filtro de todas as despesas
'desp 001
Sheets("BD1").Columns("J:T").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("BD2").Range("A1:C2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("CP").Range("A2"), _
        Unique:=False
```

As planilhas que uso nos loops são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perdão, cometi um erro crasso de achar que havia postado no internacional. Já fiz a tradução

Answer (score 0):

Faça um teste após alterar o intervalo que contém os critérios para a planilha de origem dos dados:

altere esta linha

**`CriteriaRange:=Sheets("BD2").Range("A1:C2")`**

para

**`CriteriaRange:=Sheets("BD1").Range("A1:C2")`**

Ainda, se você pretende colar os dados filtrados na planilha **`BD2`**

altere

**`CopyToRange:=Range("A2")`**

para

**`CopyToRange:=Sheets("BD2").Range("A2")`**

Se não funcionar sugiro que você disponibilize uma amostra dos dados e resultado desejado.

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida resposta,
Eu quero copiar o resultado na planilha "CP", logo o código abaixo:
`CopyToRange:=Sheets("BD2").Range("A2")`
seria na verdade:
`CopyToRange:=Sheets("CP").Range("A2")`
Porém, essa alteração não resolveu o problema.

Já a outra sugestão fez o filtro funcionar, sugerindo que o problema está na planilha "BD2". 
O meu palpite seria que a função `date` está causando algum problema com os valores das células, talvez deixando todas null. Porém não faço ideia de como resolver.

Comment: Consegui achar a solução trocando:
`c.Value = ">" & DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date)`
para
`c.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date)
 c.Value = ">" & c.Value`
Algo a ver com a diferença entre o nosso sistema de data e o sistema americana que o VBA usa
Obrigado pela ajuda